# Prepending a string to another string

Tags: c++, string

Currently, I have this code to prepend a "tag" to an exception message which gives me a very light version of a stack trace:

```
try {
    doSomething();
} catch (std::exception& e) {
    int size = 8 + _tcslen(e.what());
    TCHAR* error = new TCHAR[size];
    _sntprintf(error, size, TEXT("myTag: %s"), e.what());
    std::exception x = std::exception(error);
    delete []error;
    throw x;
}
```

It just looks horrible and I'm sure that there has to be an easy way to accomplish this. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: You've got an answer to your string processing question, but I have to say your exception handling looks pretty suspect. You've caught an exception 'e', which can be of any class derived from std::exception, but you're then effectively slicing e and losing what type e really is.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I haven't thought about it since I only throw std::exception's in the inner function. However, I now see what you mean. What would be the alternative? Altering the inner what() text directly and throwing the original exception?

Comment: *You* may only explicitly throw std::exceptions, but the STL can throw as well. If you only want to handle your own exceptions, consider writing your own exception class where you can modify the string?

Comment: ... oh, and then just "throw;" to re-throw the same exception

Comment: @Etan, don't do that! don't throw std::exception. It is just the base of a complete hierarchy. You should throw one of the derived ones provided in <stdexcept> or even implement your own ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about something like this:

`throw std::exception(std::string("myTag: ").append(e.what()).c_str());`

Added a call to c_str() and tested it in Visual Studio and it works (side note: this doesn't compile in gcc, there's only a default constructor in the implementation).

Comment: thanks! (feeling stupid that I've thinked about it for nearly an hour without ever thinking about the std::string....)

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use std::string?

```
try {
    doSomething();
} catch (const std::exception& e)
{
    throw std::exception(std::string("myTag: ") + e.what());
}
```

Other notes: 
To my knowledge std::exception does not have this form of constructor (only its subclasses do).

Not sure why you are using a TCHAR buffer. Can `std::exception::what` ever return anything but `char*`? If so, perhaps you can use `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`.

Important thing to keep in mind: what returns a `const char*` (for whatever reason). For example, it has left be wondering where the 10 or 13 characters have disappeared:

```
throw some_exception(e.what() + '\n' + moreinfo);
```

Comment: you are correct. std::exception returns a `virtual const char*`.

Comment: @fnieto: Are you downvoting _me_ because OP uses this non-standard constructor, and I even commented on it? As to not using const, I guess it is a force of habit (I actually can't remember seeing any piece of code catching it by const reference in tutorials).

Comment: +1 to counter the downvote..this is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @Naveen. Added the const if it makes you happy. But my psychic powers are failing me and I couldn't tell which exception type OP wants to throw instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there is.

```
std::string S1="Hello",S2=" World";
S1+=S2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you directly use `std::string`. You can do `std::string s = std::string("myTag") + e.what()`. And if you want char* pointer use `c_str()` member function of string.